# How to give onclick lisner to Settings option in android studio 3.6.2?

Tags: java, android

I updated my andoid studio version. In updated android studio version how to give onclick listener to settings option. when i used onclick listener to the same the drawer menu is not responding.

Screenshot of layout

[image]

This is my code snippet of activity class

```
    public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        final FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();

        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
}
```

But it should not effects to the other menu options in drawer navigation

Comment: I don't understand what you want

Comment: How to give onclick lisner to Settings option in toolbar

Comment: In attributes toolbar?

Comment: What android studio got with it?

Comment: You might consider doing the [Jetpack Navigation codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-navigation/#0) if you're unfamiliar with the code being generated by the templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [Tie destinations to menu items documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#Tie-navdrawer), you can launch a particular screen when your menu item by overriding `onOptionsItemSelected()`:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    return NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(item, navController)
        || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Then make sure that the `android:id` of your menu item (for example, the `action_settings` in your screenshot) matches the `android:id` of a destination in your navigation graph XML pointing to the `<fragment>` or `<activity>` you're using for your settings.

This same concept of ensuring that your menu item `android:id` and navigation graph `android:id` match applies to all of the menus including those used in a navigation drawer (that's how the default template's `NavigationView` works out of the box).

Answer (score 0):

You can try following source code in Activity

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        //item id
        case R.id.logout:

                            //Creating a shared preference

                            SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(Constant.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                            //Creating editor to store values to shared preferences
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
                            //Adding values to editor
                            editor.putString(Constant.ID_SHARED_PREF, "");

                            //Saving values to editor
                            editor.apply();
                            Intent intent2=new Intent(HomeActivity.this, UserLoginActivity.class);
                            intent2.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            intent2.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                            intent2.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            startActivity(intent2);

            return true;
        case R.id.settings:
            Intent intent=new Intent(HomeActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```